# Possibility to reduce nested loops

Tags: kotlin

I want to bypass deep nesting of several for-loops when creating a list off all possible `Transformations`.

Right now, this block of code is used:

```
val allTransformations = ArrayList<Transformation>().apply {
    for (moveZ in 0..4)
        for (moveY in 0..4)
            for (moveX in 0..4)
                for (rotateZ in 0..3)
                    for (rotateY in 0..3)
                        for (rotateX in 0..3)
                            add(Transformation(rotateX, rotateY, rotateZ, moveX, moveY, moveZ))
}
```

Although this is quite straight forward, I was wondering if Kotlin provides other tools to write this in a single line.

I want to retrieve the same list, with less code and see if this results in less clutter.

Comment: How would you imagine custom function to be simpler? Especially when you need to allocate variable for each loop and they have different sizes as well.

Comment: Honest answer: I don't know. More creative answer: something like `loop(0..4, 0..4, 0..3, 0..3, 0..3) { a, b, c, d, e, f -> allTransformations .add(Transformation(a, b, c, d, e, f)) }`

Answer (score 0):

This solution can be invoked with:

```
loopOverRanges(0..4, 0..4, 0..4, 0..3, 0..3, 0..3) { result ->
//    result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5]
}
```

This is defined as such:

```
fun loopOverRanges(
    vararg ranges: IntRange,
    function: (IntArray) -> Unit
) {
    val result = IntArray(ranges.size) { index -> ranges[index].first }

    val productOfRangeLengths = ranges
        .map { it.toList().size }
        .product()

    for (i in 0 until productOfRangeLengths) {
        function(result)

        result[0] += ranges[0].step
        for (rangeIndex in 0 until ranges.size - 1) {
            if (result[rangeIndex] == ranges[rangeIndex].last) {
                result[rangeIndex] = ranges[rangeIndex].first
                result[rangeIndex + 1] += ranges[rangeIndex].step
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's questionable to say the least if this improves readability. It removes the need for nesting, which can be useful for a large amount of ranges. It does not give the instant recognition of my initial nested loop; it also hides named parameters and may throw an IndexOutOfBounds when result[TOO_HIGH_INT] is retrieved.

It was a fun little investigation, but I lean towards not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with one loop. Just like incrementing a counter with 6 digits. When the first digit overflow, carry to the second digit and reset the first digit. etc.

```
fun loopOverRanges(a:IntRange,b:IntRange,c:IntRange,d:IntRange,e:IntRange,f:IntRange) : ArrayList<Transformation>
{

    val x = a.count() * b.count() * c.count() * d.count() * e.count() * f.count()
    val list : ArrayList<Transformation> = ArrayList()
    var rx = f.first
    var ry = e.first
    var rz = d.first
    var mx = c.first
    var my = b.first
    var mz = a.first
    for(i in 0 until x)
    {
        list.add(Transformation(rx,ry,rz,mx,my,mz))
        when{
            rx < f.last -> rx += 1
            ry < e.last -> {
                rx = f.first
                ry += 1
            }
            rz < d.last -> {
                rx = f.first
                ry = e.first
                rz += 1
            }
            mx < c.last -> {
                rx = f.first
                ry = e.first
                rz = d.first
                mx += 1
            }
            my < b.last -> {
                rx = f.first
                ry = e.first
                rz = d.first
                mx = c.first
                my += 1
            }
            mz < a.last -> {
                rx = f.first
                ry = e.first
                rz = d.first
                mx = c.first
                my = b.first
                mz += 1
            }
        }
        }
    }
    return list
}
```

It can be simplified as

```
fun loopOverRanges(a:IntRange,b:IntRange,c:IntRange,d:IntRange,e:IntRange,f:IntRange) : ArrayList<Transformation>
{
    data class Digit(var value :Int, val range:IntRange)
    val list : ArrayList<Transformation> = ArrayList()
    val digits = arrayOf(Digit(a.first,a),Digit(b.first,b),Digit(c.first,c),Digit(d.first,d),Digit(e.first,e),Digit(f.first,f))
    val x = digits.fold(1){acc,digit -> acc * digit.range.count() }
    for(i in 0 until x)
    {
        list.add(Transformation(digits[5].value,digits[4].value,digits[3].value,digits[2].value,digits[1].value,digits[0].value))
        val j = digits.indexOfFirst { it.value < it.range.last }
        if(j >= 0)
        {
            for(k in 0 until j )
            {
                digits[k].value = digits[k].range.first
            }
            digits[j].value += 1
        }
    }
    return list
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is however a similar solution to my own, which also combines a set of ranges to a single counter. Both solutions do not met the requirements of less code and less clutter. Therefor I'll keep the nested loops. Appreciated your input.